# how to hide div for page load and then use a show/hide function as normal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to use the hide/show function to show an image when "<div" is clicked on. When I load onto the page for the first time, the image has already loaded onto the screen. I would like the image to be hidden on page load, allowing the image to then be revealed when the  is clicked.

```js
function active01() {
  var x = document.getElementById("img01");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#img01 {
  width: 800px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="active01()" id="line01"> Exhibition_Design_The_Telephone_book_001....................2009-001</div><br>
<img id="img01" src="images/01 Exhibition design.jpg" alt="Exhibition_Design_The_Telephone_book_001....................2009-001"><br>
```

Comment: This should work fine with the code you have shown us - https://jsfiddle.net/w57dxy6L/ You need to show us a proper [mre] that actually illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");      
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Check this example

Comment: thank you @infostans. I've seen this already, the problem with this and my code is that the DIV is already on the screen when you load in. I want it to be hidden on load in.

Comment: @LouieNorman execute now

Comment: @LouieNorman please clarify what you actually want to achieve now. In your question, you talked about showing/hiding an image, and using the div as the trigger element to click on, to make the image change happen. Now all of a sudden it is the div, that is supposed to be hidden? So what do you want to click on to trigger this?

Comment: Sorry, I read the last comment I made and it was not a clear explanation. Yes, using the div as a trigger element for hiding and showing an image is what I have achieved already. The current function im running displays the image when you open the page. instead of this I would like the image to be hidden on entering the site and then revealed by clicking the div. does this make sense?